# Adding a dynamically created component to an embedded view

Tags: angular

I have a problem trying to find out how I can dynamically create a component within a priviously created embedded view.

This is the source:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[dynamic]'
})
export class DynamicDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() dynamic: Type<any>;

  constructor(
    public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    public templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    public factoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.viewContainerRef.clear();

    if (this.dynamic) {
      let ref: ViewRef = this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);

      // now I need to somehow append this newly created component into the created embedded view
      // but this way it will be place into the dom as a sibling of the created embedded view
      this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.dynamic));
    }
  }
}
```

I think the problem is that I have no idea how to obtain the ViewContainerRef for the embedded view. CreateEmbeddedView only returns a ViewRef which has no obvious possibility to add a component or even any child elements or views.

EDITED:
I use the directive like so:

```
<div *dynamic="inlineComponent"></div>
```

and in the controller:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.inlineComponent = MyComponent;
}
```

MyComponent is simply a class type

Comment: how do you use `[dynamic]` directive?

Comment: Maybe the question can be narrowed down to how I can retreive a ViewContainerRef from the returned ViewRef from the createEmbeddedView?

Comment: Check this article [Here is how to get ViewContainerRef before @ViewChild query is evaluated](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-how-to-get-viewcontainerref-before-viewchild-query-is-evaluated-f649e51315fb)